# javascript compatibility issue (firefox)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am facing the issue not of css but of javascript compatibility issue. I am working on my office project but I have no rights to share the code. I am using asp.net (VB) and I am retrieving the value on tooltip from GRIDVIEW which are hidden and getting their values through javascript on tooltip which are coming from database. All things are working perfectly tooltip also working. I am getting values on all browser through javascript except FIREFOX. Can anyone please help me?

here it is where I am facing problem in firefox

```
str="<table class='className' style='background-image:url(../../../images/tooltip1.png)'><tr><td>"+value+"</td></tr></table>";
$('.toolTip .content').html(str).css('background','transparent');
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the rendered html through browser dev tools?  Without seeing the code is it a simple clientidmode= static

Comment: You need to give some more details about what issue you are facing or what is the error on Firefox when you do some operations. Don's share whole code but you can simply share demo/sample kind of code to have more idea about it.

Comment: Currently I am using parentElement.nextSibling.innerText in condition. and than it is showing on tooltip which is also coming from javscript code like $('.toolTip .content').html(str).css('background' , 'transparent');

Comment: I have run on firefox console and I am not getting any error and also not getting value.